# Text would not display on IE only

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

As my title, I have test other browsers firefox, chome, safire, and IE.
Only the IE won't display the text on the menu bar.
The one I was viewing is IE9.
Please help.

Sample as following:
http://joeewu.com/Tester/Lindsay/

Thanks for viewing.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the joys of cufon ..

First thing you should do is update to the latest version of Cufon.

Then add this code to your header before any `Cufon.replace()` calls:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        Cufon.set('engine', 'canvas');
   </script>
<![endif]-->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment: `if gte IE 9` is unnecessary. `if IE 9` is all that is needed. IE10 doesn't support conditional comments at all ;)

Comment: They started doing that in IE9. IE10 is the next step up. It's now ahead of Chrome, actually, as Webkit still uses all the `-webkit-` prefixes on things that are now standard.

Comment: Hi Kaloyan Ivanov, Thanks for the quick reply. Will try and see if it works. Thanks! Do I need to take off "<!-- -->" out for the 5 lines?

Comment: No, don't take it out, that's a conditional statement that only IE's can read.